# Is equivalent this expression to Wilson's theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

According to [Wilson's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), $n$ is prime if and only if (1):

$$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$$

Would the following expression be valid and equivalent? (2)

$$1\equiv-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\pmod{\frac{n}{(n-1)!}}$$

I am doing the following transformations based on the equivalent proportions of the interval $[0..n!]$ into the interval $[0..n]$ (basically via [rule of three](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three)):

> If the value $n!$ of the interval [0..n!] is the value $n$ of [0..n] then in the same proportion:
>
> $(n-1)! \to 1$
>
> $1 \to \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$
>
> $n \to \frac{n}{(n-1)!}$

Wilson's statement (1) is equivalent for some valid $k$ to the expression:

$$(n\cdot k)-1=(n-1)!\ \ $$

thus replacing proportionally the values and for some $k'$ also proportional to $k$:

$$(\frac{n}{(n-1)!}\cdot k')-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=1$$

Meaning that the expression (2) would be also true and equivalent to (1) if the applied logic is correct.

I am doing this exercise for the purpose of learning: I wanted to try to express Wilson's theorem using relationships inside the interval $[1,n]$ instead of using relationships expressed over $[1,(n-1)!]$. That is the reason to try to convert all the quantities into their equivalent values in the interval $[1,n]$.

I just know basic modular arithmetic so I am not sure if it is correct to set a fraction as the value of the congruence in the expression (2).

According to these ideas:

> 1. Would (2) be a correct equivalent expression of (1)? Is the conversion rule that I applied valid?
> 2. If it is wrong, is there a way to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: How would you define $a\equiv b \pmod {q}$ where $a,b,q$ are rational numbers?

Comment: @DarthGeek thank you for the hint, wythagoras' answer helped me to understand that the notation is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo arithmetic is usually not considered with non-integers.

However, if you mean that 1 and $-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ differ an integer multiple of $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$, then the answer is yes. However writing it as such is abuse of notation.

---

You could write $$-1 \equiv (n-1)!^{-1} \mod n$$

Where $(n-1)!^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $(n-1)!$ mod $n$. Which exists because $n$ is prime. However, $(n-1)!^{-1}$ is an integer and this does not really mean the same thing as you wrote.

---

I think the best is saying that $\large{-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}$ and $1$ differ an integer multiple of $\large{\frac{n}{(n-1)!}}$.

Comment: this is very appreciated thank you, I always use modulo arithmetic only with integers, so in this case I was not sure if it was valid or not, so the notation is not correct in this case (if I understood correctly the concept behind is valid, because $\frac {1}{(n-1)!}$ and $1$ differ an integer multiple of $\frac {n}{(n-1)!}$)